# What is the difference between struct node* node and struct node *node?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, structure

I am new to pointers and I don't know this. Please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't any difference. You cold also write `struct node  *  node`.

Comment: The spaces makes no difference. Your question use the the name 'node' for both a data type and a data name - this isn't syntactically correct, but the comment are still correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no semantic difference, it's a purely stylistic choice.